# django-cms redirect top level menu to first child

Tags: django, django-cms

I would like to redirect the top menu items in a page I'm writing to point at their children if they have any. E.g. this site has a top level About, with several CMS pages underneath. When a user clicks on about, I want to show the first child page under the top-level about menu.

I can do it like the below, but it feels wrong. I know I can do a static redirect, but I don't want to do that, as the first child might change (it's a CMS system after all) and I don't want the people entering data into the CMS to have to manage a redirect. So I prefer the below to a configured redirect.

This is a pretty common requirement, is there a standard way of doing this? I think I might be able to do it with a [navigation modifier](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/extending_cms/app_integration.html#navigation-modifiers), so I might try that route next.

```
    <div style="display:none;">{% show_menu 0 1 1 %}</div>
    <div id="topmenu">
      <ul>
      {% for child in children %}
          <li>
          {% if child.children %}
          <a href="{{child.children.0.get_absolute_url}}">
          {% else %}
          <a href="{{child.get_absolute_url}}">
          {% endif %}
          {{ child.get_menu_title }}
          </a>
          </li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

About the above, I need to have the show_menu in there otherwise the data isn't there for my custom menu. Is there any way for this not to be needed?

The thing I dislike the most about the above, is that the /about/ page is still active. It's not the worst thing in the world if someone browses there, they'll get an empty page, but I'd rather that not happen. I think if I wrote a navigation extension the same disadvantage would be there. I guess I need a programmatic redirect to redirect to the first child if that page is hit. Thoughts? I can probably do it in template logic, but that seems crazy.

Comment: have you found a solution with Navigation Modifiers? As of django-cms 3.0, there still seems no good solution, besides my little hack proposed below...

Comment: @benzkji not really, we're most often just setting the redirect on the top level page, I think your little hack is as good as any solution

Comment: ok then. my hack frees you from adapting the redirect value every time the first childs url changes. depending the scenario, this can be a real benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2018:** updated version, that works in cms 3.4+ and new middleware style compatible [available here](https://github.com/bnzk/djangocms-misc/blob/develop/djangocms_misc/basic/middleware/redirect_subpage.py). Once you added the /firstchild, you'll need to edit/publish the redirecting page in the cms pages's change list, as, you guess it, will redirect.

---

solution with middleware and custom redirect field value of "/firstchild", to trigger redirects.

- plus: you won't have any blank pages
- plus: it's flexible, as it allows pages that will not be redirected to subpages
- plus: no action needed when the first child's url changes
- minor drawback: there is always a redirect ( 301, though, not that bad ;)
- minor drawback: configuration is a bit nerdy, as you will have to enter "/firstchild" into the "redirect" field. definitely not end-user friendly, but works. the cms itself doesnt provide a better solution at all (not even in 2018).

---

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# redirect to first subpage if the "redirect" field is exactly "_subpage"
class RedirectSubpageMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if request.current_page:
            page = request.current_page
            if "slug" in view_kwargs and page.get_redirect() == "/firstchild":
                subpages = request.current_page.children.all()
                if subpages.count():
                    # can redirect! must make uri!
                    return redirect(subpages[0].get_absolute_url(), permanent=True)
        return None
```

Comment: Great answer, I fixed a bug where it would always redirect, preventing you from publishing the page.

Comment: Any idea how to make this recursive? I've tried, but it keeps going to an absolute url ending in /_subpage/

Comment: thx @kin. this middleware is older than publishing, ie 2.4 ;-). page.get_absolute_url will always return the "correct" path with an url containing "_subpage/"...should add a recursive helper function, when back from holidays ;-)

Comment: @Kin can you add that fix to my answer, i.e. edit it?

Answer (score 3):

You might consider setting the CMS_REDIRECTS = True in the settings.py file.

Then you can go into the /about/ page in the admin and add the redirect to /about/child-page

Note: I haven't actually tried this, I just happened to stumble across this information this morning.

Comment: Yeah, that's easy, I've tried that and it works, but I don't want to have any hard-coded links that people have to maintain. The solutions really has to redirect to the first child, whatever that first child is.